# Vectorize only some arguments in function when calculating on Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, vectorization

I have written a function that is meant to calculate a new dataframe column based on two other columns, as a few points of data from another dataframe. I want to apply this function in a vectorized way to the main dataframe, such that the 2 column inputs are calculated in such a way. At the same time, I want the third argument to be a constant dataframe that is used for a separate interpolation calculation (i.e not vectorized). How can this be accomplished?

### Main function (as an example):

```
def calc_fitted_values(L, option, df_ref):
    '''
    This calculates an outputval for each combination of L and option, based
    on intermediate calculations involving fitted values from df_ref.
    - L is some column in my main dataframe
    - option is a second column in the main dataframe
    - df_ref is a separate data frame used in the pre-calculations here
    '''
    df_ref_option = df_ref[df_ref['option']==option]  # take slice of df_ref based on option
    x = df_ref_option['x'].values                         # get data columns to be used for polyfit
    y = df_ref_option['y'].values
    C = np.polyfit(np.log(x), np.log(y), 1);   # use polyfit to get log fit of the reference data
    a = np.exp(C[1]);
    b = C[0];  
    outputval = a*(L**b)
    return outputval
```

## Usage wanted from function:

```
df['outputval']] = calc_fitted_values(df['L'], df['option'], df_ref)
```

In this example, `L` and `option` will be array values obtained from my main data frame columns (`df`), but `df_ref` is unrelated in in terms of shape and size.

How can I best write a function for this type of situation?

Thanks.

EDIT: My current "solution" is to use lambda...

```
f = lambda L, option : calc_fitted_values(L, option, df_ref)
df['outputval'] = np.vectorize(f)(df['L'].values, df['option'].values)
```

But this appears to be very slow. Might be due to the calculation each time through with `df_ref`, so would it be better to have a function that returns a lambda-defined function? Not sure of the best approach to this.

Comment: one possible solution: torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss
https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/equivalent-of-tensorflows-sigmoid-cross-entropy-with-logits-in-pytorch/1985

Comment: If you use `np.vectorize` (for convenience, not speed), try the `exclude` parameter. And don't neglect the `otypes` parameter.

Comment: the parameter `option` is not used ...

Comment: @B.M. sorry, fixed it

Answer (score 0):

You can use `partial`

```
from functools import partial

func = partial(calc_fitted_values, df_ref=df_ref)

df['outputval'] = np.vectorize(func)(df['L'], df['option'])
```

I hope this helps

Comment: @teepee Have you had the chance to try `partial`method?